# Get Browser Width and Height Excluding Toolbars and Menu Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I need a Js / JQuery Script , which return me browser's available width and height excluding menu bar and toolbar size , i am using one script but it seems to be returning width / height including toolbar ect...

below is script i have used..

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
var winWidth = 0, winHeight = 0;
        if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
            //Non-IE
            winWidth = window.innerWidth;
            winHeight = window.innerHeight;
        } else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
            //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
            winWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            winHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
            //IE 4 compatible
            winWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            winHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        }
</script>
```

Any body have any clue on this?
Thanks
Meghana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery , you can have the following :

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Comment: thanks @Mathboy , but i come to know that my post if not as per of my requirement...  i am adding new post... plz help me if you have any idea as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should return the usable size of your browser window. In my case, on a 1920x1200 display, I get 1920x1106. My taskbar is 40 pixels tall, so that leaves 54px for the titlebar of the window.

Comment: you are right... i checked my code once again , its returning me browser height / width excluding toolbar and etc. Actually , i have user's screen resolution and need browse width / height. i need to do some calculation with proportional to user's screen resolution , but it is not retuning me correct result. now i come to know that... i need width / height of browser window  including toolbars and ect... exactly opposite to my current post :). so i should make another post.. plz help me there as well if any idea. thanks again.

Comment: `screen.width` and `screen.height` will give you the user's screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<input type='button' id='btn1' value='test'/>

$('#btn1').click(function(){
alert($(window).width());       
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Pu2Ej/

Comment: thanks @Bui Cuong , but i come to know that my post if not as per of my requirement...  i am adding new post... plz help me if you have any idea as well :)